# How can I write back IDs to original records from Process Builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, automation

I currently have a process builder that creates a new record when certain criteria are met. Is there a way that I can write the ID of the newly created record back to the original record that started the process?

Example of desired behavior:

1. Process Builder Runs
2. New record is created
3. ID of newly created record is written back to a field on original record that started the process

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Process Builder, you cannot. Process Builder actions do not store state in the way that you need to do this.

You can do so with Flow. In a Flow, you can capture the Id of a [Record Create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_fast_create.htm) result back into the originating sObject variable.

> If you used an sObject variable to create a single record, the sObject variable’s ID field is updated with the new record’s ID value. If you used an sObject collection to create multiple records, the ID field of each collection item is updated with its matching new record ID value.

You can then use that value to perform an [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_fast_update.htm) against the originating record.